# How to overcome a blocking 3rd party function

Tags: c, winapi

I am using some 3rd party functions (hrmcom.dll) in my win32 application. I have a main windowclass with a winproc and 3 childwindows, all of a second windowclass that share one childproc.
The call to the 3rd party functions is in one of the childwindows and handled in the childproc based on a WM_COMMAND (a button is pushed and the functions are called).

One of these functions is blocking. It makes connection to a IrDA device and it 'hangs' when the device is not present and in connect mode. I wanted to take care of this situation with a timeout of the call.

What I tried is to call SetTimer (call at the same window as from where the blocking function is) just before the blocking call and define a WM_TIMER handle. This is not working, debugging shows that the function hangs and the WM_TIMER event is never handled. I tried to call the timer for the main window, but that is also not working.

I saw a working example of this DLL in where one button is used for starting and cancelling the proces of connection to the device.

Question: How could I deal with the hanging function and time it out after X seconds when it is not connecting to the device? I have been reading about threads, but i was wondering if it really can only be done that complicated (I have not been able to get threads work so far).

Below is the header file part of the called function, if that helps:

```
__declspec (dllexport) BOOL CALLBACK fnHRMCom_StartIRCommunication  (int, LPTSTR);

//  Return value:
//  BOOL bStartOK
//   TRUE           - Starting of communication made succesfully
//   FALSE          - Problems encountered, check the following possible   errors:
//                      * Communication has already been started and it is running
//                      * Communication port already reserved for some other device
//                      * Maybe call was made from 16-bit program. A 32-bit DLL cannot
//                        create an additional thread when that DLL is being called by
//                        a 16-bit program.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Latest code included:
The thread function (simplified):

```
VOID Thread(PVOID pvoid)
{
volatile PPARAMS pparams;
pparams = (PPARAMS) pvoid;

if (pparams->bContinue)
{

    if (!fnHRMCom_ResetIRCommunication(0))
    {
        // Resetting IR connection was not successful
        ErrMsg(L"Resetting IR connection was not successful");
        return;
    }
    if (!fnHRMCom_StartIRCommunication(HRMCOM_PARAM_IRDA, L"IR"))
    {
        // IrDA couldn't be opened, stop connection thread
        fnHRMCom_EndIRCommunication(FALSE);
        ErrMsg(L"IrDA couldn't be opened, connection thread stopped");
        return;
    }
    //Status report "IR Communication started"
    SetWindowText(hwndCtrl[11], L"Status: IR Communication started");

    if (!fnHRMCom_ReadMonitorInfo(&psg, &psmi))
    {
        // Reading failed, close connection
        if (pparams->bContinue)
        {
            fnHRMCom_EndIRCommunication(FALSE);
            ErrMsg(L"Reading failed, connection closed01");
            SendMessage(hwndCtrl[8], LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            fnHRMCom_EndIRCommunication(FALSE);
            ErrMsg(L"Connection aborted, connection closed");
            SendMessage(hwndCtrl[8], LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }

    }
    // End IR communication
    fnHRMCom_EndIRCommunication(FALSE);
}
_endthread();


}
```

Code for calling and cancelling the Thread manually:

```
case (ID_CTRL + 12) : 
        //Cancel connect to device
        params.bContinue = FALSE;           
        if (!fnHRMCom_EndIRCommunication(FALSE))
        {
            //TODO: Error
            return 0;
        }
        TerminateThread(hThread, 0);    
        return 0;       
    case (ID_CTRL + 7) : 
        //Load Activities from Device
        params.bContinue = TRUE;
        if (IDCANCEL != MessageBox(hwnd, L"Make sure your device is set to connectmode", L"Warning", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION))
        {
            //Start downloading the activities in separate thread
            SetTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1, 10000, NULL );
            hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(Thread, 0, &params);
        }
        //cancelled, dont start the IrDA connection thread      
        return 0;
```

And the code for the timer handler:

```
case WM_TIMER:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDT_TIMER1)
    {
        if (!fnHRMCom_IsIrDAConnected())
        {
            SetWindowText(hwndCtrl[11], L"Status: IrDA connection timed out");
            TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
            fnHRMCom_EndIRCommunication(FALSE);
            KillTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1);                
            ErrMsg(L"IrDA connection timed out");               
            return 0;
        }
        else KillTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: If it had been on Linux (or any other POSIX-compliant system) you could have used `alarm(3)`.

Comment: @Klas: How does this magically cause the 3rd-party function to return? If it doesn't then how is this particular way to crash your application superior to placing the function call in its own thread and crashing that? I mean, except for the geek factor of using 70s technology.

Comment: @Klas: So, what you're saying basically boils down to this: The advantage of `alarm(3)` is that it solves the problem, as long as the problem does not exist. Or, in other words, a well-behaved 3rd-party function is well-behaved. This is somewhat offtopic, as the question is specifically asking for a problem resulting from a 3rd-party function that isn't well-behaved.

Comment: @Klas: If the community is anything like what I believe it is, then providing a POSIX not-quite-a-solution-unless-the-problem-doesn't-exist to a question with a *winapi* tag doesn't add any value. At all. Sorry. I provided insight to one of the answers, in case you actually care. Given your profile, however, it appears that you would rather take any chance to point out that Windows isn't POSIX-compliant, instead of actually providing help.

Comment: @Klas, IInspectable, I suggest that the two of you take this discussion outside this topic.

Comment: @IInspectable I have deleted my other comments. If you have a problem with my original comment, don't hesitate to flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the blocking call into it's own thread.

Your threading function could be as simple as something like this:

```
volatile BOOL success;
volatile BOOL done;

void ConnectThread() {
    success = false;
    done = false;
    if (!fnHRMCom_StartIRCommunication(123, "Some Stuff")) {
        std::cerr << "There's been some IR problem." << std::endl;
        done = true;
        return;
    }
    success = true;
    done = true;
}
```

Then just do your timeout outside, waiting for some signal, in this example `done` to be set. If the timeout period is over without `done` being set, you know that it's taking too long (and you can kill the thread), otherwise you're able to read `success` to determine whether it worked.

Comment: It would be nice to give C example, when OP is tagging the question with C ;)

Comment: @Mario: Thanks for the reply. So using your thread function, i would call it from the handler with the "start" button with CreateThread(NULL, 0, ConnectThread, pPARAM, 0, NULL). And assum that the the success en done variables are global, I would check them based on a timer in that handler. When the timer times out i call the ExitThread(ConnectThread). I dont think any clean-up is needed, since the 3rd party calls use their own cleanup functions. I would call that functions too when a time-out occurs. Now all i need to do is code it and try. I will keep you posted on the result.

Comment: Yep, something like that, but you might want to put your result values in a struct and pass it as a param to the thread so you don't have to use globals for this.

Comment: I tried to make a handle for calling the thread with _begintread. That works ok. The thread is started and it does not block the main program. When i try to end the thread from the main program in a handle that responds to a message (a cancel button is pushed) I seem only be able to use the terminatethread function. The result is that the thread still seems sort of alive. When i call it again (push the start button) it is in an error status. Not sure how to explain this better, hope it makes sense.

Comment: @gedysan: A thread started with `_beginthread` terminates by returning from its thread proc. If another thread needs to terminate this worker thread, it should not ever force a `TerminateThread` call on it - the result will be unpredictable. Instead, it should ask the thread to terminate, by signaling an event object for example. However, as long as the thread is waiting for a function call to return, there is nothing you can do to respond.

Comment: @IInspectable: So the above solution is not correct? I am terminating the thread from the main thread. What i found out is that terminating the thread makes the blocking function fail and the bool is returning false. That means it hits the error code part belonging tot that function. This is not too bad. I tested it and it seems to work now. But i am sure that its not correct design pattern, given your comment. Could someone please review it and give me some hints?

Comment: @Mario: I added the code of my project status as of today. could you please have a look?

Comment: Not sure whether `if (pparams->bContinue)` is what you want (doesn't make any sense to me). Also you're not calling `_endthread()` for your error cases. But besides that, looks probably ok.

Comment: Thx Mario. I already thought about the if statement myself. My thoughts were to use it instead of your done/success option. But when i have time again, i will refert back to that option (reading in the main thread if done and/or success are in place). I will fix the error cases as well (so far testing does not call the error cases).

Answer (score 0):

You might also find it interesting about canceling pending i/o operations in Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363789(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thx for the hint. I am not sure if the DLL implementation is compatible with the cancellation of IO threads. But I will give it a try and see what happens. I think the only thing i need to do is replace the TerminateThread call by: CancelSynchronousIO(hThread)? I will report back

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work. I dont notice a different behaviour from the outside. The thread is terminated. Not sure which option to use now. Documentation is not clear on that. The 3rd party DLL provides a function to end com as well and i call that just before ending the thread. Maybe that explains why there are no differences (not sure how things work under the hood(